# SQLITE: Query to get data in a table format

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, pivot

I have the data in this format:

```
Prod    Name    Qty
-------------------
Ink     Joe     100
Pen     Joe      10
Ink     Jay      50
Pen     Jay       5
```

I would like to write an SQL query which returns the data in this format:

```
 Prod    Joe     Jay
 ---------------------
 Ink       100      50       
 Pen        10       5
```

Please note that both Prod and Name, are dynamic(The number of Prod entries and Name entries keep varying)
Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: you are looking for a PIVOT.  try searching on that

Comment: Thanks Randy, this looks to be the right thing. I am looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select prod,
  max(case name when 'Joe' then Qty end) Joe,
  max(case name when 'Jay' then Qty end) Jay
from tablename
group by prod
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mGP3kNYA8RbLxHfTGT8pSr/2)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the Prod and Name is dynamic. So, I cannot hardcode the name

Comment: You can't name the sqlite table columns dynamically by sql. You must do it programmatically.